# Adding every input - Python code

Tags: python, loops

```
while True:
    credit = 0.00
    coins = input("Please enter 10p, 20p, 50p or £1: ")
    value = ["10p","20p","50p","£1"]
    if coins not in value:
        print("Coins not accepted")
    while coins == ("10p"):
       money = credit + 0.1
       print (money)
```

This is my code so far.
What i'm trying to achieve is: if the user then again enters 10p, the code will then add it onto the credit. Then if the user enters 10p again, the code will add another 0.1 to the credit, making the output 0.2.
I haven't been able to figure it out. Help would be very appreciated.
How can I make my code not refresh the credit back to 0.00 but keep on adding 0.1 whenever I input 10p?

Comment: Please fix your indentation. The people trying to help you need to see the correct indentation to know what your code will do.

Comment: It's not a good practice to use floating point numbers to store/calculate money

Answer (score 0):

I would change how you accept your input but this will do what you want but  you will have [floating point issues](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)  :

```
credit = 0.00

money_dict = {"10p":.10,"20p":.20,"50p":.50,"£1":1}
while True:
    coins = raw_input("Please enter 10p, 20p, 50p or £1: ")
    if coins not in money_dict:
        print("Coins not accepted")
        continue
    else:
        credit += money_dict[coins]
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you're wanting to print money when you're adding value to credit (which gets zero-ed on every iteration of the loop).

Since you want money to increment, we'll just take out credit entirely and add money to itself every time you input a new value. (Note that I took out the symbol in my example).

Simple solution:

```
money = 0.00

while True:

    coins = raw_input("Please enter 10p, 20p, 50p: ")
    value = ["10p", "20p", "50p"]

    if coins not in value:
        print "Coins not accepted"
    elif coins == "10p":
        money += 0.1
    elif coins == "20p":
        money += 0.2
    elif coins == "50p":
        money += 0.5

    print money
```

Ran example:

```
Please enter 10p, 20p, 50p: 10p
0.1
Please enter 10p, 20p, 50p: 10p
0.2
Please enter 10p, 20p, 50p: 50p
0.7
Please enter 10p, 20p, 50p: 10p
0.8
Please enter 10p, 20p, 50p:
```